# Make animation keyframes repeat infinitely

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, countdown

I am making a countdown timer circle. The animation works fine on the first iteration, but the circle animation always stays full after the first iteration and does not rest. The number continues to work correctly and rests back to 20, counting down again. I need the red countdown line to copy this.

First time:

[image]

Second time:

[image]

I have tried adding things like

```
 animation: circletimer 59s linear infinite forwards;
```

and

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite
```

But I can't seem to make the animation happen more than once.

The code that I currently have is:

Countdown component -

```
interface IProps {
  countdown: number
}

const CountDownCircle: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({
  countdown,
}) => {
  console.log(countdown)
  return (
    <div className={'countdown__circle'}>
      <svg className={'countdown__circle-svg'} width="200px" height="200px">
        <circle className={'circle'} cx="100" cy="100" r="28" />
      </svg>
      <span className={'timer'}>{countdown}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
export default CountDownCircle
```

css(scss) -

```
.countdown__circle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 34px;
  right: 47px;
}

@keyframes circletimer {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
    stroke-dasharray: 500;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 500;
  }
}
.countdown__circle-svg {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateZ(-90deg);
  .circle {
    stroke: $red;
    stroke-width: 5;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    animation: circletimer 59s linear infinite forwards;
  }
}
.timer {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  color: $black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: $proximaBold;
}
```

How to make this animation happen infinitely?

Answer (score 0):

You must remove **forwards** from your aniamtion, as forwards indicates that animation stays like it is after the first run.

```
animation: circletimer 59s linear infinite;
```

W3Schools description for aniamtion-fill-mode:forwards is: "The element will retain the style values that is set by the last keyframe (depends on animation-direction and animation-iteration-count)"